# Understanding Javas HttpSession

Tags: session, jetty, httpsession

I have a little problem with HttpSession.
I use jetty 8 and try to implement an embedded web server.

For testing purpose i have created two servlets:

- FileServlet: It simply handles HTTP GET for static content, like index.html, css
  and other static files and prints the current session id on the
  console:

> System.out.println("File session: "+request.getSession(true).getId()
>   + " path "+request.getPathInfo());

- TestServlet: Does nothing, it simply prints the current session id on the console on a doGet(...)

> System.out.println("Test session: "+request.getSession(true).getId()
>   + " path "+request.getPathInfo());

As far as i know the Servlets must be part of the same ServletContext to handle Sessions correctly. So i implement it programmatically this way:

```
Server server = new Server(8081);    
ServletContextHandler servletContext = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
            servletContext.setContextPath("/");
            servletContext.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new FileServlet()),"/*");
            servletContext.addServlet(new ServletHolder( new TestServlet()),"/servlets/test");
server.setHandler(servletContext);
```

Now I start my web-browser (Chrome btw.) clear browsers cookies and browsers chache and load my test site http://localhost:8081/index.html which will also request to load other static files like css and js.

So now i get this output:

```
File session: ok49uty1mshn1fnhyle9ojh3n path /index.html
File session: 1fuxdd50woxwv1gl9r96dfdxgl path /css/style.css
File session: 1f6m5dkht4xja5ryj7dgd93wu path /css/Loading.css
File session: 1qizt3gnyy58uj0u46kofbxdf path /css/photo.css
File session: ikzpmgyew49uwxlnt8lr839m path /css/Login.css
File session: pg6p843xuqak1uwcc68q8wnxx path /js/script.nocache.js
File session: 1uv2jmvpu5u6s127rpc01ef8 path /js/script2.js
```

After index.html has been loaded and every other resource that is embedded in index.html (css and js) i call http://localhost:8081/servlets/test and i see this output:

```
Test session: 1uv2jmvpu5u6s127rpc01ef8 path /servlets/test
```

So it seems to me that it takes some time to establish a session and i am wondering why and how to let the first session that has been created by the HTTP GET of /index.html be the session for every futher server interaction. Its very strange.

I also make a second experiment:
As a said before i cleared the browsers cache and cookies before loading /index.html. This time i reload the page without clearing the cache and cookies, and now it works correctly or in other words, how i expect to work:

```
File session: 1uv2jmvpu5u6s127rpc01ef8 path /index.html
File session: 1uv2jmvpu5u6s127rpc01ef8 path /css/style.css
File session: 1uv2jmvpu5u6s127rpc01ef8 path /css/Loading.css
File session: 1uv2jmvpu5u6s127rpc01ef8 path /css/photo.css
File session: 1uv2jmvpu5u6s127rpc01ef8 path /css/Login.css
File session: 1uv2jmvpu5u6s127rpc01ef8 path /js/script.nocache.js
File session: 1uv2jmvpu5u6s127rpc01ef8 path /js/script2.js
```

And also /servlets/test have the same session:

```
Test session: 1uv2jmvpu5u6s127rpc01ef8 path /servlets/test
```

EDIT: i understand that my browser doesnt wait until the index.html is loaded completly and start to load the css and js in the meantime... But I really need to be able to determine from the first HTTP GET the "real" session for some security reasons. Any suggestions?

Comment: To be 100% sure of what's happening here, you should get a dump of the HTTP headers each way. Something like wireshark can do that for you, or you can look at in your browser (using something like [LiveHttpHeaders](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/) for Firefox, or [net-internals](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=2f76303d4e166cdd&hl=en) for Chrome. You need to get a true picture of what's passing between the server+client in order to see when cookies are being set/sent, rather than guessing from your server logs.